# Testing action text with rspec

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

Using action text, I have a model named `drill` with

## app/models/drill.rb

```
class drill
   has_rich_text :content
end
```

I have a form to use the trix editor

```
<%= form_for @drill do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.rich_text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end -%>
```

This produces a space to enter text, with the label 'Content', an input with id of `drill_content_trix_input_drill`, a `trix-editor` element with an id of `drill_content`. In the rspec feature spec, I have tried

```
it 'fills the content field', js: true do
    ...
    fill_in 'drill_content_trix_input_drill', with: 'Do full swing very slowly'
end
```

but this gives

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "drill_content_trix_input_drill" that is not disabled
```

I have also tried `fill_in 'Content'` and `fill_in 'drill_content'` but saw a similar error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57319708/how-to-test-actiontext-using-rspec

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
  def fill_in_trix_editor(id, with:)
    find(:css, "##{id}").click.set(with)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a method called [`fill_in_rich_text_area`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionText/SystemTestHelper.html#method-i-fill_in_rich_text_area) provided by Rails that can be used instead of `fill_in` now.